# `python -m pdb myscript.py` - how to automatically "continue" after start?

Tags: python, pdb

When running a python with pdb, like

```
python -m pdb myscript.py some_arg another_arg
```

I don't want it to ask me what to do. I want it to "continue" immediately. Is there a way to do that? Is there a way to do that without editing the global pdb configuration in *~/.pdbrc*?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can't set breakpoints or do much of anything useful with pdb that way. It's mostly equivalent to just running the script without pdb.

Comment: I want to enter debugger if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 3):

```
python -m pdb -c continue myscript.py some_argument another_argument
```

From pdb docs:

> *pdb.py* accepts a `-c` option that executes commands as if given in a *.pdbrc* file, see [Debugger Commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).